Define a function with an optional argument of a generic collection of values and provide a default if the argument is None
How can you define a function that accepts as its argument, an optional collection of values where the collection is a generic type that implements the IntoIterator trait. If the argument is None, the function should set a default value.
For example, this accepts an optional vector of integers and if None is provided, sets a default:
fn vectors(optional: Option<Vec<u32>>) {
    let options = optional.unwrap_or(vec![1]);
}

How can you generalise this for any collection type such as an array or other iterable?
This
fn has_optional_argument<T: IntoIterator<Item = u32>>(optional: Option<T>) {
    let options = optional.unwrap_or(vec![1]);
}

produces the compiler error mismatched types:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:6:38
    |
5   | fn has_optional_argument<T: IntoIterator<Item = u32>>(optional: Option<T>) {
    |                          - expected this type parameter
6   |     let options = optional.unwrap_or(vec![1]);
    |                            --------- ^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found `Vec<{integer}>`
    |                            |
    |                            arguments to this method are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected type parameter `T`
                       found struct `Vec<{integer}>`
help: the return type of this call is `Vec<{integer}>` due to the type of the argument passed
   --> src/main.rs:6:19
    |
6   |     let options = optional.unwrap_or(vec![1]);
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------^
    |                                      |
    |                                      this argument influences the return type of `unwrap_or`
note: method defined here
   --> /home/james/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/option.rs:990:12
    |
990 |     pub fn unwrap_or(self, default: T) -> T {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^


Because type T is a into iterator, try call map it into_iter() and collect to a vec before unwrapping

@啊鹿Dizzyi: Collecting an iterator ahead of time can be a serious behavior change, and is completely impossible for infinite iterators, for example.
